# Использование PHP Session и VueJS

Tags: php, vue.js

Всем привет!
После долгих раздумий решил разделить монолит на микро сервисы и в качестве фронта использовать VueJS.
Назрел вопрос в котором я не нашел ответа на просторах интернета, как мне использовать сессии в VueJS для авторизации\контроля доступа, как мне передавать\принимать контент из office.example.com
Структура проекта такая:

```
exaple.com (VueJS Front)
auth.example.com (API)
office.example.com (API)
```

Использовать JWT нет пока возможности.
Может кто наталкивался на примеры?
Важный момент, мы не используем Vue CLI...

Comment: Поясни-ка а где связь vue и сессии? Сессии используются в транспорте, а Vue это просто рисовалка морды.

Comment: Александр - Давайте перейдём к транспортной основе? Что вы используете в качестве транспортной основы? fetch, axios, websocket или другой способ? От вашего ответа зависит как именно PHP будет удобно передать ваш SESSION_ID...

Comment: Пока еще нечего, собственно чего и задан вопрос как можно это реализовать.

Comment: Я пока сам не понимаю как будет проходить авторизация пользователя и контроль доступа

Comment: Это мой первый опыт работы с раздельным фронтом от бекенда

Answer (score 0):

Для начала тебе что-бы сессия работала на всех серверах одинаково, тебе надо перенести её на отдельный сервер. В базу данных или лучше в какой memcached. Потом реализовать интерфейс `SessionHandlerInterface` https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php если используешь на backend какой-то готовый фреймворк типо ларавел, то там скорее всего это уже есть решение из коробки (https://laravel.ru/docs/v3/session/config) Database Session, Memcached Sesssion.

Далее тебе на всех доменах нужно реализовать Cors. Статей по поводу настройки Cors в интернете навалом.

Реализовать на всех серверах SSL сертификаты.

Ну и наконец правильно настроить транспорт, так что-бы тот-же fetch знал что к этому домену нужно передать так-же session_id.

*ps: А что-бы не заниматься жесткой любовью со всем этим, есть хорошая добротная альтернатива, поставить reverse proxy например `haproxy` И не делить домены, а использовать pathbased проксирование. Например: example.com/api проксировать на один сервер, example.com/ переводить на loopback example.com/office проксировать на сервера офиса.*

Comment: Сессии уже хранятся в Redis

Comment: Редиска тяжеловесная штуковина, если только сессии хранить, как из базуки по воробьям стрелять. Мой совет - хотя-бы глянь документацию на haproxy или nginx в режиме reverse proxy. Скорее всего вопрос сам по себе отвалиться. Даже сисадмину будет проще мониторить состояния серверов с haproxy на каком ни будь Zabbix. Чем делить реальными доменами.

Comment: Redis хранить сейчас не только сессии, в нем куча частей скомпилированного шаблона, динамический конфигурация и некоторые промежуточные данные... По физике он расположенный на отдельной машине. Ну а так буду испытывать ваш вариант.